# PHP Local development - minikube or docker-compose?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am developing a PHP application - meaning for development I just use a base `php` container without copying any application code.

My `docker-compose` setup looks like this:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
    db:
        image: postgres:10.0
        container_name: app-db
        ports:
            - 65432:5432
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret

    web:
        image: falnyr/php-images:7.2-apache-postgres
        container_name: app-webserver
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - 8081:80
```

So ports are forwarded to localhost and volumes are mounted. The `docker-compose.yml` file would be committed to the repository so anyone cloning the code would be able to run `docker-compose up` to get it running.

Switching to Kubernetes I'd like to keep the same behavior for **development** only, so generally having a `Deployment` with following spec:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php-app
      tier: backend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php-app
        tier: backend
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: src
        hostPath:
          path: /home/falnyr/projects/php-app
      containers:
      - name: php-app
        image: falnyr/php-images:7.2-apache-postgres
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/www/html
          name: src
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

I am well aware of the fact that `hostPath` (under `volume`) doesn't support relative path since the `Pod` has no idea about the current working directory.

All I need to do is provide a way to all of the devs to just pull the code, run a command and make it running. I can imagine this could be handled via `makefile` but I'd really like to avoid that if there is an easier way.

Question is what is the best-practice approach to the local development of PHP apps? Should we stick to `docker-compose` or use Kubernetes with `minikube` instead?

Comment: I'd say the best approach for PHP development is to avoid containers and use something like XAMPP: https://www.apachefriends.org/

Comment: I can't point out how many reasons are there against usage of XAMPP, what century did you come from?

Comment: I really would like to now the many reasons against the usage of XAMPP.

Comment: You are tied to your host machine. What about multiple versions of PHP in projects that you work on? What about custom PHP extensions? What about additional parts of the stack outside of Apache, Mysql and PHP? Redis? Elasticsearch? A different database like Postgres? Not even mentioning microservices in production that you need to match with your local environment. If all you think of PHP world is just WordPress, Joomla, Drupal etc. then go for XAMPP. It just doesn't work for software development.

Comment: @falnyr Do you currently use makefile, or maybe you've found another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it really matter the fact that it is PHP? Would it be any different if it would be python, for example?

If not, then you should consider [helm](https://helm.sh/). It is a package manager for kubernetes. You just do `helm install package` and it installs all the dependencies for your complete app to work.

With helm, I think, you can build your own custom charts.

Comment: That doesn't solve the `hostPath` issue as the `CWD` is unknown. I still have to build the values using `makefile` or something.

Comment: My answer was to &amp;quot;how to make an easy installable app&amp;quot; for your team. Sorry. Can't you define it in a variable, then refer to it?

Comment: Well yep, the only thing that sounds reasonable is to use `makefile` to find out `CWD` and populate the config values with it.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/), you can use `postStart` script to set up your dependencies:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: lifecycle-demo-container
    image: nginx
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]
```

In section command, you can execute any kind of scripts in your container.